# How would i work out magnitude quickly for 3 values?

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

How can I use a Fast Magnitude calculation for 3 values (instead of using square root)? (+/- 3% is good enough)

```
public void RGBToComparison(Color32[] color)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    foreach (Color32 i in color)
    {
        var r = PivotRgb(i.r / 255.0);
        var g = PivotRgb(i.g / 255.0);
        var b = PivotRgb(i.b / 255.0);

        var X = r * 0.4124 + g * 0.3576 + b * 0.1805;
        var Y = r * 0.2126 + g * 0.7152 + b * 0.0722;
        var Z = r * 0.0193 + g * 0.1192 + b * 0.9505;

        var LB = PivotXyz(X / 95.047);
        var AB = PivotXyz(Y / 100);
        var BB = PivotXyz(Z / 108.883);

        var L = Math.Max(0, 116 * AB - 16);
        var A = 500 * (LB - AB);
        var B = 200 * (AB - BB);

        totalDifference += Math.Sqrt((L-LT)*(L-LT) + (A-AT)*(A-AT) + (B-BT)*(B-BT));
    }
    totalDifference = totalDifference / color.Length;
    text.text = "Amount of Pixels: " + color.Length + "  Time(MilliSeconds):" + DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds + "                                  Score (0 to 100)" + (totalDifference).ToString();
    RandomOrNot();
}
private static double PivotRgb(double n)
{
    return (n > 0.04045 ? Math.Pow((n + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4) : n / 12.92) * 100.0;
}    
private static double PivotXyz(double n)
{
    return n > 0.008856 ? CubicRoot(n) : (903.3 * n + 16) / 116;
}    
private static double CubicRoot(double n)
{
    return Math.Pow(n, 1.0 / 3.0);
}
```

This is the important part:  `totalDifference += Math.Sqrt((L-LT)*(L-LT) + (A-AT)*(A-AT) + (B-BT)*(B-BT));`

I know there are `FastMagnitude` calculations online, but all the ones online are for two values, not three. For example, could i use the difference between the values to get a precise answer? (By implementing the difference value into the equation, and if the difference percentage-wise is big, falling back onto square root?)

Adding up the values and iterating the square root every 4 pixels is a last resort that I could do. But firstly, I want to find out if it is possible to have a good `FastMagnitude` calculation for 3 values.

I know I can multi-thread and parllelize it, but I want to optimize my code before I do that.

Comment: Sorry,im new here. I dont really get how this is a wall of text; Its 8 lines, and the lines are short. The code is also only 27 lines, and i think it could be helpful if you know the maths i used to work out the LAB values

Comment: Is this any better?

Comment: Thank for the help! :)

Comment: Have you profiled if the root is actually the operation that slows things down? There is no point in optimizing it if it has almost no influence. Another option to improve performance is to use parallelization, which can be done trivially for this algorithm.

Comment: I have profiled, and this is the root cause of the slow down. I want to parallelize after i have optimized the algorithm. Even with a Parallel, this algorithm is still too slow for my application (Its a primary part of my application)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare the values, why not leave the square root out and work with the length squared?

Or use the [taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties_and_uses) of the square root of 1+x and cut off early :)

Comment: Ill try it, but preferbly i want it to have the correct scale, and i think that it is possible to have it accurate, using a mixture of working out difference and having square root as a fallback.

Comment: Did the profiler verify that the square root is the current bottleneck?

Comment: Square root is definitely the bottleneck

Comment: Then use its taylor series to approximate it. I had the exact same problem once back in the early nineties writing a 3D game in dos :D

Comment: Added link to the taylor series to my post :)